# Adding leading zero to a column in place using zfill

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column called CIPCODE in a dataframe called df.

I am trying to add leading zeros to the CIPCODE column (in place) using zfill as follows:

```
df['CIPCODE'].zfill(7)
```

the error I am getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'zfill'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zfill()` function is a string function.  Also, if you want the change to stick, you should place your expression on the RHS of an assignment.

```py
df["CIPCODE"] = df["CIPCODE"].str.zfill(7)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `.str.zfill(7)`.

Or if the column is not string type, `.astype(str).str.zfill(7)`